# Firestore join foreach map - get data from two collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, foreach, google-cloud-functions

Hey Guys i need your help one more :(
I dont know how I make a Join or something else in Firebase

I have two collections:
collection("guests")  has a datafield "Eventid" and a datafield "Userid"
in the first step i select all guests with a specific Userid. So i get all Eventids in a foreach loop (or as an Array)! In the second Collection
collection('events') I select all Information and write it in a JSON File. This works too after a couple of time and this is my problem!
I run this in a funktion and the function return before the Events were loaded.
I dont know how i use it i tried it with await and async or split it in two functions.
Maybye there is another way to realize it.

```
db.collection("guests").where("userid", "==", id).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        db.collection('events').doc(doc.data().eventid).get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            } else {
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i got it!

```
exports.getEvent = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    console.log('==NACHEINANDER STARTEN==');
  
    const id = req.query.uid;
    var arr = [];
    var json = [];
    let query =  db.collection("guests").where("userid", "==", id);
    

await query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
            arr.push(documentSnapshot.data());
        });
    });
    //console.log(arr);
await processArray(arr)     


async function delayedLog(item) {
    await db.collection('events').doc(item.eventid).get().then(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.data());
        json.push(doc.data());
    })

}

async function processArray(array) {
    const promises = array.map(delayedLog);
    // wait until all promises are resolved
    await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log('Done!');
 }


console.log("hello");


    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(json)); //, ...userData
});
```